# Custom TeamCity plugin save button

Tags: java, maven, jsp, plugins, teamcity

I'm developing custom Runner type for TeamCity. I got far enough to have new runner type registered in TC with simple JSP saying "Hello WOrld". However, when I click on "Save" button, nothing happens. Looking at server log I don't see any error. Is there any JS function I need to implement in my custom JSP in order to make this work? Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had problem with implementation of PropertiesProcessor in getRunnerPropertiesProcessor(). Once fixed, TC was able to save runner configuration.